# Hay alguna manera de exportar los datos de una BD para pasarla a una nueva BD con más información y actualizada?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

estoy haciendo un sitio web para una empresa y estoy trabajando en diferentes etapas, digamos, primero subo una parte del sitio web funcional mientras trabajo en las secciones futuras.
El caso es que estoy creando más tablas y columnas en la base de datos del localhost ya que con cada etapa estas necesitan tener mas información.

Lo que debo hacer es copiar todos los datos de la base de datos existente alojada en el phpMyAdmin del Hosting, insertarlos en la nueva base de datos que tiene más columnas, etc, y luego volver a cargarla nuevamente en el servidor sin perder la información que ellos ya tenían, por ejemplo los usuarios registrados en la web.

Esto se debe a que cada vez que subo la Base de Datos al Hosting restablece los valores de las tablas, prácticamente deja la base de datos vacía.

(Estoy usando MySQL de manera remota para la gestión de la base de datos y phpMyAdmin directo desde el cPanel del Hosting).

Comment: Hm. Se me ocurre que mantengas control de versiones en tu proyecto y, a medida que liberas cosas nuevas, generes un parche para la BD con _la diferencia_ entre la última versión y lo que estás liberando.

Comment: Create una nueva base de datos vacia en tu cpanel, y alli subes la base de datos local, y luego desde phpmyadmin inserta los registros a pelo desde las tablas viejas a las nuevas (que sean distintas, las que no han cambiado no hace falta), y una vez lo tengas conseguido copias las tablas nuevas que has tenido que rellenar sobre las viejas (es trabajo minucioso pero no se me ocurre otra, y quizas no tanto si hablamos de pocas tablas... entiendo que no te pasas todo el dia cambiando la estuctura de las tablas)

Comment: Para la parte de [migracion mysql](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-mysql-database-between-two-servers) deberias hacer primero un `dump`, luego copiar la base de datos y por ultimo, importarla

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @Alfabravo Gracias por la respuesta, me gustaría saber cómo hago eso del Parche de la BD, ya que creo que sería lo ideal.

Comment: @masterguru Gracias por responder, creo que entendí pero no del todo, osea paso la nueva base de datos al servidor (la que está vacia), y Lugo hago un importe de la base de datos vieja? En teoría de esa manera rellenará con la información anterior?

Comment: @M.K Gracias por tu respuesta, de esa manera podré digamos de alguna manera "Actualizar" la base de datos del servidor y mantener la información que está tenía?

Comment: @ByJuanii Una vez tengas importada tu base de datos local (con cambios en la estructura) en la nueva base de datos de cpanel, la cual llamarás "temporal" para no confundir con la real, debes identificar las tablas de las cuales has modificado su estructura, y mediante la pestaña SQL realizar las consultas pertinentes para la copia de los registros respectando todos los datos (ids incluidos supongo), de tal forma que la temporal tenga por un lado la nueva estructura y por el otro los datos reales ya copiados.

Comment: @ByJuanii y cuando estes seguro que eso esta bien entonces puedes borrar la tabla real (siemper haz copia de seguridad antes de nada) y copiar la de la base de datos temporal, y asi uno a uno.  Para ello puedes utilizar la pestña Operaciones... TODO ESTO DESDE PHPMYADMIN me refiero, ojo.